# Problem reading out parameter from stored procedure using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, out-parameters

I just come across a strange problem where i cannot retrieve the sql stored procedure out parameter value. I struck with this problem for nearly 2 hours.

Code is very simple

```
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_mgsearach", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@SearchTerm", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            param1.Value = searchTerm;
            param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@start", SqlDbType.Int);
            param2.Value = start;
            param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
            SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@end", SqlDbType.Int);
            param3.Value = end;
            param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);
            SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@total", SqlDbType.Int);
            param4.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            param4.Value = 0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);


            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            LoadHits(reader);           
            if (lstHits.Count > 0)
                total = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@total"].Value);
            else
                total = 0;

        }
```

the @total value is always null. But when i execute the query generated through profiler in query analyzer , it returns fine.

Finally i found this is due to the SQL Connection.

It works fine if i **close the connection before reading the out param**

```
            LoadHits(reader);           
            con.close()
            if (lstHits.Count > 0)
                total = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@total"].Value);
            else
                total = 0;
```

WT.., i just cant figure out why it behaves like this.. anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameter values are returned at the **end** of the TDS stream (since you could change it at the end of your query, after selecting data). You must be sure to consume **all** the TDS data (or at least, cause the buffers to be flushed, which `Close()` does for you) in order to get the updated parameter values, for example:

```
do { while(reader.Read() {} }
while (reader.NextResult());
```

The same goes for SQL errors raised late in the query. You could also try adding a `using`; this may also be sufficient:

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    LoadHits(reader);  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to Marc's answer, you can just close the reader (not the connection) to get the results.

This is well documented ("Closing the DataReader"): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=VS.100).aspx