# C# SqlCommand, XmlReader and output parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, xmlreader, sqlcommand, output-parameter

i have a problem with receiving value of output parameter when i execute stored procedure using SqlCommand. I don't have problem with output parameter when i execute stored procedure not from C# code, but from SQL Server Management Studio. Here is fragment of my C# code:

```
    rest = -1;
    XmlDocument res = new XmlDocument();
    res.LoadXml("<Result><ErrCode>0</ErrCode></Result>");
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = Params.SqlCn.CreateCommand())
    {
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "dbo.wss_doProductAdd_sp";
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@quantity", ilosc));
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@addToLog", addToLog));
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rest", rest).Direction =           ParameterDirection.Output;
    XmlReader xr = sqlCmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
    XmlNode newNode = res.ReadNode(xr);
    while (newNode != null)
    {
    res.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode);
    newNode = res.ReadNode(xr);
    }
    xr.Close();
    Params.SqlCn.Close();
```

I've found this:
[Problem reading out parameter from stored procedure using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803240/problem-reading-out-parameter-from-stored-procedure-using-c-sharp)
I added a line that closes reader but it didn't helped. And some user from the link above uses LoadHits method, and i cannot find it in MSDN or in Google.

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to read the parameter. Have you actually checked sqlCmd.Parameters[2].Value after you execute the query to see its value?

Comment: Oh, I thought that this line "sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rest", rest).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;" will automatically cause inserting value to rest variable. Thank you for post, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment solved your problem, I thought I'd add it as an answer:

I don't see where you're trying to read the parameter. Have you actually checked sqlCmd.Parameters[2].Value after you execute the query to see its value?